# Why does Gmail force header text to the left and image to the right?

Tags: android, html, email, gmail

I am sending an email campaign that consists mainly of a single image for the body and two sentences of text side by side for the header on top of the image. The email looks perfectly fine on desktop and even Outlook, but as soon as it opens in Gmail and the Gmail app on Android, it breaks and the header text is forced to the left while my image is forced to the right. Here is a sample:
[Gmail Misalign Sample 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6DgW.png)

I know Gmail is weird with tables and I've tried several suggestions on this site but nothing seems to work. If anyone sees what I am doing wrong I'd greatly appreciate the help.

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Chase Run Realtor Preview - March 22, 2016</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    
    
<style type="text/css">
  body,#bodyTable,#bodyCell{
   height:100% !important;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   width:100% !important;
  }
  table{
   border-collapse:collapse;
  }
  img,a img{
   border:0;
   outline:none;
   text-decoration:none;
  }
  h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
  }
  p{
   margin:1em 0;
   padding:0;
  }
  a{
   word-wrap:break-word;
  }
  .ReadMsgBody{
   width:100%;
  }
  .ExternalClass{
   width:100%;
  }
  .ExternalClass,.ExternalClass p,.ExternalClass span,.ExternalClass font,.ExternalClass td,.ExternalClass div{
   line-height:100%;
  }
  table,td{
   mso-table-lspace:0pt;
   mso-table-rspace:0pt;
  }
  #outlook a{
   padding:0;
  }
  img{
   -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
  }
  body,table,td,p,a,li,blockquote{
   -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
   -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
  }
  .mcnImage{
   vertical-align:bottom;
  }
  .mcnTextContent img{
   height:auto !important;
  }
  a.mcnButton{
   display:block;
  }
  body,.backgroundColor{
   background-color:#c9c8c5;
   background-position:top left;
   background-repeat:repeat;
  }
 table { border-collapse:collapse; 
      mso-table-lspace:0pt; 
      mso-table-rspace:0pt; 
     }
 
</style></head>
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" yahoo="fix" offset="0">

<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
 <tr>
     <td width="100%" valign="top" bgcolor="c9c8c5" style="padding-top:20px">
            
<!-- BEGIN PREHEADER // -->
                                        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="665">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td valign="top" style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:9px;"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="center">
                
                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="366">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        
                        <td valign="top" style="padding-top:9px; padding-left:18px; padding-bottom:9px; padding-right:0;">
                        
                            <span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #606060;">Experience Luxury - Chase Run Realtor Preview</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
                
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="220">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        
                        <td valign="top" style="padding-top:9px; padding-right:18px; padding-bottom:9px; padding-left:0;">
                        
                            <a href="*|ARCHIVE|*" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; color: #606060; font-size: 12px; font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>View email in your browser</strong></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
                
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table></td>
                                                 
<!-- END PREHEADER // --> 
   
<!-- MAIN BODY START // -->   
            
<table width="665" height="1120" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="deviceWidth" margin="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
 <tr align="center" style="line-height:0;font-size:0;">
        
  <td align="center" style="line-height:0;font-size:0;min-width:665" height="1120" margin="0">
        <div style="height:1120px; max-width:665px; min-width:650px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/0c1d06cd6f55ea378fdda7348/images/323ca46e-43bf-4caf-b110-ba41fffc09f5.png" style="display: block; min-width:650px;" width="665" height="1120" alt="Chase Run Realtor Preview - March 22nd"></div></td>
        
</tr></table> 
        <table width="665" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="deviceWidth">
                    <tbody><tr>
     <td align="center" style="padding-top:16px; padding-right: 18px; padding-bottom: 9px; padding-left: 18px; min-width:665; font-size: 12px; font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif; color: #606060;">
   
    <a href="*|UNSUB|*" class="utilityLink" style="text-decoration: none; color: #616161;">unsubscribe from this list</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="*|UPDATE_PROFILE|*" class="utilityLink" style="text-decoration: none; color: #616161;">update subscription preferences</a>&nbsp;
    <br>
    <br><br>
    

                        </td>               
               
</tr></table></td></tr></table></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gmail ignores `<style>` tags

Comment: Your code is not valid HTML, I see that the pre header is not properly closed. Also it's not recommended to say `<table align="left">` and `<table align="center">` next to each other. Use one `table` with two `<td>`'s that are next to each other with the text inside it.

Answer (score 0):

For emails in particular it is best to avoid style tags in the header. Majority of clients don't read them, and it is generally accepted that in the email environment it is best practice to do style inline. One thing, if you really want to use styles it may be a good idea to get litmus to test the email in various environments.